# moving video up with css

Tags: html, css

I am currently trying to move this image up. However every time I try and mess with the top and bottom elements nothing happens. I'm assuming it's just a simple fix but I can't see to find where I went wrong. I possibly have something nested where it shouldn't be is my guess. If anyone could help me with this that would be fantastic! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in the iframe rule - that might be the cause, since the absolute positioning won't work as expected:

```
iframe{
...
possition: absolute; ---> must be "position"
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You have position spelled wrong in your CSS.